# Any callback after jQuery file upload UI renders the download template

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have some data got back from the server through an ajax post done inside 'fileuploaddone' callback. I need to update the download template which is rendered by the jQuery file upload UI with this data.

Is there a way  to accomplish this? Any callback function or something that can be invoked after the template is rendered?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another event 'fileuploadpostdone' in which I was able to update the template